# positioning of iframe with <!doctype html> active

Tags: html, http, iframe

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NAPL</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="main" method="post" enctype="text/plain" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <iframe id="dict" align="right" src="dict.html" width="15%" height="80%"></iframe>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just starting to learn html.
If I issue from the server the text bellow and I ommit `<!doctype html>` then everything works as expected regarding the positioning and size of the iframe.
Actually if I put `<!docttype html>` everything changes and I don't know more how to have the same previous effect in the simplest way.

Comment: "everything works as expected". You should change your expectations, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the doctype, browsers switch to quirks mode. I don't know the exact intricacies of these horrendous behaviors, but the standard equivalent CSS seems something like

```css
body {
  margin: 8px; /* Usually the default value */
}
#dict {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80%;
}
```